# Teach Coq that associative law of natural numbers holds

Tags: coq

I have a simple question.

I want to teach Coq that there is vec_assoc.

```
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.

Lemma vec_assoc (A:Type)(a b c:nat): t A ((a+b)+c) = t A (a+(b+c)).
Proof.
f_equal. symmetry. apply Nat.add_assoc. Qed.

Variable a b c:nat.
Variable A B:Type.
Variable  I : (t A ((a+b)+c) -> B).
Variable p:t A (a+(b+c)).
```

Coq returns an error

```
`The term "p" has type "vector A (a + (b + c))" 
while it is expected to have type "vector A (a + b + c)".`
```

When I execute `Compute I p`.

How do I teach Coq that associative law of natural number holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, associativity does not hold with respect to convertibility of Coq terms, it only holds propositionally. What that means is that in a context where `a, b c : nat` you can build a term `pf : a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c` but it is not the case that the specific proof `eq_refl` can be given the type `a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c`.

In your case, since you already have a proof that `t A (a + (b + c)) = t A ((a + b) + c)` you could do the application by first transporting `p` along this equality using `eq_rect` or the `rew vec_assoc A a b c in p` syntax from the module `EqNotations` of the standard library (just add `Import EqNotations.`).

In any case nothing will compute since both `I` and `p` are variables (and the proof `vec_assoc` is opaque thanks to `Qed`).